# How to stop/kill the query of perticular user?

Tags: asp.net

I have created one webform(using C#).Onclick of button,I am executing query,showing time that sp take.I want to stop/kill that query.How to find out query which is executed by perticular user.I want to kill  query of perticular user not other.How to do that?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about what conditions or user you are taking in account but you can stop execution of the sql query anytime based on your condition either on database or c# code.

just use this query when you needed
`RaisError ('Sorry, Your operation can't be completed', 15, 10)`